# I am trying to match two separate columns with respective data (CSV)

Tags: python, pandas, csv

As the title says, I am trying to store two different columns into sort of a dictionary. I am using pandas to do this and to be quite honest... still learning pandas as I work on this project. Here is what I am trying to do:

Mock Example CSV:

```
column1 |   column2  | column3
Burgers    McDonalds    3.00
```

What I am trying to do is create a dictionary where it would be like:

```
data = { "Burgers": 3.00}
```

I am trying to do this with pandas and a for loop? Are these even the right steps to go about this? Below is my source code.

```
import tkinter 
import csv
import pandas as pd
import seaborn as sns
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np 


data_set_2017 = pd.read_csv("2017.csv")
data_set_2018 = pd.read_csv("2018.csv")
data_set_2019 = pd.read_csv("2019.csv")
data_set_2020 = pd.read_csv("2020.csv")

#country_2020 and rank_2020 are the two columns I am trying to pair the values with...
country_2020 = data_set_2020["Country name"]
rank_2020 = data_set_2020["Ladder score"]

for i in country_2020:
    for k in rank_2020:
        test = pd.DataFrame({ i: [k]} )
        
print(test)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This one line code will do the job, and it is faster than for loops:

```
res_dict = dict(zip(data_set_2020["Country name"], data_set_2020["Ladder score"]))
```

Answer (score 1):

With "data.dat" as:

```
column1 |   column2  | column3
Burgers    McDonalds    3.00
```

Code:

```
data = {}

with open("data.dat", "r") as msg:
    raw_data = msg.readlines()

for line in raw_data[1:]:
    items = line.strip().split()
    data[items[0]] = float(items[2])

print (data)
```

Output:

```
{'Burgers': 3.00}
```

To me, your way of doing it is quite complicated. As you have CSV files, you can do that way in a more efficient manner. You can also loop through the csv files in the current directory and make a list of dict if needed:

```
import glob

list_dict = []

for filename in glob.glob("*csv"):

    data = {}
    
    with open("data.dat", "r") as msg:
        raw_data = msg.readlines()
    
    for line in raw_data[1:]:
        items = line.strip().split()
        data[items[0]] = float(items[2])
    
    list_dict.append(data)
```

Comment: Thanks for this, I appreciate the explanations by showing me the "with open" way. Thanks for this information.